# I wonder how to use mixstock package

Tags: r, function, error-handling, package

I'm studing a mixed stock analysis based on walkthrough provided by Bolker (https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=043730a02b148396ebd54b2f62e8f6364714b1b2), using the 'mixstock' package.

I had some problems while practicing the package. An error occurred in the process of graphing the many-to-many analysis, so the graph presented in the example does not appear. Could you possibly solve that problem?

[image]

i want to make this graph, but

[image]

My code made this graph.

This is my code.

```
Z = simmixstock2(nsource=4,nmark=5,nmix=3,
          sourcesize=c(4,2,1,1),
          sourcesampsize=rep(25,4),
          mixsampsize=rep(30,3),rseed=1001)
Zfit0 = mm.wbugs(Z,sourcesize=c(4,2,1,1),returntype="bugs")
plot(as.mcmc.bugs(Zfit0))
plot(Zfit0)
```

Also, can I put my own data other than random data into the "simmixstock2" command? I want to do it once with my data, but the manual command seems to generate it only randomly, so I would like to know if there is a way. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```r
library(mixstock)
Z = simmixstock2(nsource=4,nmark=5,nmix=3,
          sourcesize=c(4,2,1,1),
          sourcesampsize=rep(25,4),
          mixsampsize=rep(30,3),rseed=1001)
Zfit0 = mm.wbugs(Z,sourcesize=c(4,2,1,1), pkg="JAGS", jags.seed = 101)
plot(Zfit0)
```

The changes are

- use JAGS instead of WinBUGS (which may be nearly obsolete - in any case, hard to run on platforms other than Windows; I don't know the status of OpenBUGS), including setting the seed for the MCMC run
- *don't* specify `returntype = "bugs"` (instead, the default "mixstock" option gives something that we can plot)

I'm not quite sure what you mean by

> can I put my own data other than random data into the "simmixstock2" command ?

The `simmixstock2()` function is **designed for simulating data** in the case where you want to see how things work when you don't have your own data. There are instructions in the vignette/walkthrough on pp. 4-5 about how to input data for multiple mixed stocks (add them as additional columns to a matrix (with rows = haplotypes, columns = sources and mixed stocks) and specify the number of mixed stocks (`nmix=1` by default) when using `as.mixstock.data()`).